# Why presize a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

Firebug represents `(new Array(N))` as an array with `N` `undefined`s in it. I recently ran across a scenario that demonstrated that a sized array with all `undefined` values in it is different from a newly constructed, sized array. I'd like to understand the difference.

Suppose you want to generate a list of random integers between 0 and 1000.

```
function kilorange() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1001));
}

no_random_numbers = (new Array(6)).map(kilorange);
my_random_numbers = [undefined, undefined, undefined,
                     undefined, undefined, undefined].map(kilorange);
```

I would have expected `no_random_numbers` and `my_random_numbers` to be equivalent, but they're not. `no_random_numbers` is another array of `undefined`s, whereas `my_random_numbers` is an array with six random integers in it. Furthermore, after throwing a `console.count` statement into `kilorange`, I learned that my function never gets called for the array created with the Array constructor.

What is the difference, and why does `map` (and presumably other iterable methods) not treat the above arrays the same?

Comment: @FelixKling Just a bit ahead of you, thanks to davin's comment below. But this brings out the title question. What good is it to create an empty array with a nonzero length?

Comment: The only example I've ever seen using it is `new Array(6).join("some text")` which will repeat "some text" 6 times.

Comment: It is not of any good, that's why no one is doing this. But it's in the specification, and you cannot just drop it without breaking some scripts. What *could* be an advantage is that the `length` of the array does not have to be increased every time set a new element, though the performance gain is probably negligible.

Comment: Wait, what the heck? @Tetaxa, *why* does that work?

Comment: @kojiro I'm not sure, but I guess it's in the javascript specs, there are test cases for it here http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/test/mjsunit/array-join.js?r=8922

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ES standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (15.4.4.19) defines the algorithm for `map`, and it's quite clear from step 8b that since your array doesn't actually have any of those elements, it will return an "empty" array with length 6.

As others have mentioned, it has to do with array objects in js being (unlike their rigid C counterparts) very dynamic, and potentially sparse (see 15.4 for the sparsity test algorithm).

Comment: Props for documentation! I found 15.4.2.2 to be relevant, as well. If I read it correctly, `new Array(len)` is equivalent to `(new Array())` followed by directly setting the length property. But what purpose could that serve?

Comment: @kojiro, for example, in theory if the compiler can ascertain that elements won't be added to the array beyond the prescribed length and other properties aren't accessed, then instead of implementing a normal object (which more closely resembles a hash map), it could use the much faster C-like array to optimise.

Answer (score 2):

When you use:

```
var a = new Array(N);
```

no values are stored in the new array and even the index "properties" are not created. That is why `map` won't do a thing on that array.

The fact that Firebug does that is a bug/feature of the Firebug. You should remember that it's console is an `eval` envelope. There are other bug/features in the Firebug console.

For example in Chrome console you'll see the above `a` array as `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this sample and run it: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtPD/1/ (it create the two arrays without using the `map` over them and then list the key/values of each one of them)

I would say that `(new Array(6))` doesn't allocate "named" properties (so it doesn't create "1": undefined, "2": undefined...) while the other form `[undefined, ... ]` does.

In fact if I use a `for (var i in ... )` the two outputs are:

```
no_random_numbers


my_random_numbers
0 undefined
1 undefined
2 undefined
3 undefined
4 undefined
5 undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question, good answers. I fiddled a bit with the `map` prototype from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). If it's adapted like this, `map` would work for a `new Array([length])`

```
Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {
    var T, A, k;
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined");
    }
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = O.length >>> 0;
    if ({}.toString.call(callback) != "[object Function]") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
    }
    if (thisArg) {
      T = thisArg;
    }
    A = new Array(len);
    k = 0;
    while(k < len) {
      var kValue, mappedValue;
      if (k in O || (O.length && !O[k])) {
//                  ^ added this
        kValue = O[ k ];
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
        A[ k ] = mappedValue;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return A;
};
```

Based on Casy Hopes answer you could also make a `mapx`-extension to be able to use `map` with some `new Array([length])`:

```
Array.prototype.mapx = function(callback){
  return this.join(',').split(',').map(callback);
}
//usage
var no_random_numbers = new Array(6).mapx(kilorange);
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I wouldn't call it `Array.map` since, apparently, the current no-op behavior of `(new Array(n)).map(fn) is correct. Would want to mislead someone with intuitive, incorrect behavior. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question (why presize arrays), the only use that I've come across for initializing an `Array(n)` array is to create an `n-1` length string:

```
var x = Array(6).join('-'); // "-----"
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer *why* you would presize an array, you'd do it so you don't have to do as many individual allocations. Allocating memory takes some time, and it might trigger a garbage collection run that can take a lot longer.

On a typical web page, you won't notice a difference, but if you're doing something major, it might help a fair bit.